# Extract specific features from a CSV File

Tags: python

I would like help simplifying my code. I am taking in a CSV file with 8 columns and extracting the information from it. I have used the library `import csv`. I need to sift through the csv file and see if an element in column 5thc has either the value of 1,2,3,or 4.

```
        #read the csv file from the command line
        csv_read=csv.reader(csv_file)

        #Extract rows from csv file into a list  

        for row in csv_read:
             rows=list(csv_read)

        #Exact necessary features from that list (some aren't needed, I used a dictionary method)
        rowsp = [(a,b,c,e,f) for (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) in rows]
        
        #From list above (rowsp) I am trying to searching for a particular port number that is either [1,2,3,4] that is in the  4th column. I used some mapping.
        resultfilter1 = [player for player in rowsp if player[3] == '1']

        #from the search above I want to extract other features that will be used in the future
        result = [(b)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultfilter1]
        result_something1=[(c)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultfilter1]
        result_something2=[(a)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultfilter1]
        result_tb=[(c,e) for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultfilter1]
        

        #Look for another port from the rowsp this being 2:
        resultafilter2 = [player for player in rowsp if player[3] == '2']
        resulta = [(b)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultafilter2]
        result_c2ip1=[(c)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultafilter2]
        result_st1=[(a)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultafilter2]
        result_tb1=[(c,e) for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultafilter2]
        
       
        #look for another port which is 3 and so on
        resultbfilter3 = [player for player in rowsp if player[3] == '3']
        resultb = [(b)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultbfilter3]
        result_c2ip2=[(c)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultbfilter3]
        result_st2=[(a)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultbfilter3]
        result_tb2=[(c,e) for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultbfilter3]
        
   ]

        resultcfilter4 = [player for player in rowsp if player[3] == '4']
        resultc = [(b)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultcfilter4]
        result_c2ip3=[(c)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultcfilter4]
        result_st3=[(a)for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultcfilter4]
        result_tb3=[(c,e) for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultcfilter4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function to handle the same logic of your `resultfilter`:

```py
        def result_something(pid):
            resultfilter = [player for player in rowsp if player[3] == pid]
            #from the search above I want to extract other features that will be used in the future
            result_b  = [(b)   for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultfilter]
            result_c  = [(c)   for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultfilter]
            result_a  = [(a)   for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultfilter]
            result_ce = [(c,e) for (a,b,c,d,e) in resultfilter]
            return result_b, result_c, result_a, result_ce

        result_1_b, result_1_c, result_1_a, result_1_ce = result_something('1')
```